# Converting an IIF statement into case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone convert this statement into CASE Statement in SQL Server?

```
IIf((LoanBalance)=0 And CurrentPrincipal<>0 And EndPaymentDate>MaxOfPayment_Date,iif(Pledged_Loan=True,1,2), IIf(LoanBalance=0 And currentprincipal<>0,3,IIf(OffCycle_Payment=True,4,5))) AS POFF
```

Comment: Asking people to do your work for you is highly frowned upon. Showing people the case statement you came up with and asking for help fixing it is a much better approach.

Comment: Sure,  I understand what you are saying. This is what I have come up with which I should have posted and have someone correct. Could you help now?

Comment: , CASE
           WHEN LoanBalance = 0 and CurrentPrincipal<>0 And EndPaymentDate>MaxOfPayment_Date AND Pledged_Loan = 'True' THEN 1
            WHEN (LoanBalance = 0 and CurrentPrincipal<>0 AND EndPaymentDate>MaxOfPayment_Date) AND Pledged_Loan = 'False' THEN 2
            ELSE CASE WHEN LoanBalance = 0 AND CurrentPrincipal<>0 THEN 3
                        ELSE CASE WHEN Offcycle_Payment = 'True' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END
          END     
END AS

Comment: Add that to your question rather than as a comment so it won't get overlooked... and surround your code within backticks (or indent it 4 spaces) so it will look like code.

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` statements cascade (meaning the first matching condition is chosen and no others).  So, you don't have to nest the logic using `case`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN LoanBalance = 0 And CurrentPrincipal <> 0 And 
                  EndPaymentDate > MaxOfPayment_Date and
                  Pledged_Loan = True
             THEN 1
             WHEN LoanBalance = 0 And CurrentPrincipal <> 0 And 
                  EndPaymentDate > MaxOfPayment_Date
             THEN 2
             WHEN LoanBalance = 0 And CurrentPrincipal <> 0
             THEN 3
             WHEN OffCycle_Payment = True
             THEN 4
             ELSE 5
       END) AS POFF
```

Comment: And how does it not work?  Presumably, something like "True" is not defined, because that is not a construct in SQL Server (unless it refers to a column).  You should put in whatever the appropriate value is.

Comment: Gordon, the case statement does not match with the logic of the IIF statement. that is why it does not work.

Comment: @Amani . . . Can you describe how the logic is different?  The logic looks the same to me.

Answer (score 0):

I  think that would be something about like this:

```
CASE WHEN   LoanBalance=0
        And CurrentPrincipal<>0
        And EndPaymentDate>MaxOfPayment_Date
        THEN CASE WHEN Pledged_Loan=True THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
    WHEN LoanBalance=0
        And currentprincipal<>0
        THEN 3
    WHEN OffCycle_Payment=True
    THEN 4 ELSE 5 END END AS POFF
```

Ah, and I believe boolean in SQL Server would be stored as a bit, so that would make it this:

```
CASE WHEN   LoanBalance=0
        And CurrentPrincipal<>0
        And EndPaymentDate>MaxOfPayment_Date
        THEN CASE WHEN Pledged_Loan=1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
    WHEN LoanBalance=0
        And currentprincipal<>0
        THEN 3
    WHEN OffCycle_Payment=1
    THEN 4 ELSE 5 END END AS POFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LoanBalance = 0 
                 AND CurrentPrincipal <> 0 
                 AND EndPaymentDate > MaxOfPayment_Date
            THEN CASE WHEN Pledged_Loan
                      THEN 1
                      ELSE 2
            END
            ELSE CASE WHEN LoanBalance = 0 AND currentprincipal <> 0
                      THEN 3
                      ELSE CASE WHEN OffCycle_Payment
                                THEN 4
                                ELSE 5
                           END
                 END
        END AS POFF
```